# logind.cof file in ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, shutdown

I have heard that the logind.conf file should be in /etc/systemd/logind.conf. however, it doesn't appear there, and a file search reveals that it isn't ANYWHERE.

So what file replaces logind.conf, or where can I find it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Nothing replaces it. Rather, in Ubuntu 12.04, that file **doesn't exist *yet***.

This file only exists on systems that either use *systemd* as the init (boot) system, or at least have its *systemd-logind* component installed separately, and this is only available starting with Ubuntu 13.04.

(Even then, chances are that systems with *systemd-logind* alongside Upstart won't even care about many of the settings in logind.conf, anyway. The functions might be part of some another program, like acpid...)

So, you should instead describe the *configuration* that you want to change, rather than some magical file. Go a few steps back, remember what you wanted to do that led you to logind.conf, and [ask about that](https://superuser.com/questions/ask).

Comment: I was trying to make the power button do nothing when pressed as my computer's power switch is broken and will randomly shut down the computer from time to time. I ended up being able to fix it by running this command:

 gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power button-power nothing

anyway, the problem persists because sometimes it is held down, forcing the computer to hard power off. I will need to buy a new front panel...